# Angular2 Nested Inputs in components in a form - controls array is empty

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, nested

i am having issues with nested inputs in components in a form component in angular 2. The controls array of my mainForm is empty - therefore i cannot use form validation in my form.

I've created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZsT4MMexUqdLxSCy4maj?p=preview) to demonstrate the issue.

FormComponent

```html
<form #mainForm="ngForm">
  <customer-input ngControl="customerAccount"></customer-input>
  
  {{mainForm | json}}
</form>
```

Customer-Input

```html
<div class="form-group"> 
    <label>{{label}}</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" (keyup)="onKeyup($event)" #REF (change)="onChange(REF.value)" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Any help regarding how to add inputs inside nested components to a form in angular 2 is highly appreciated